# Using a Command to Open a Window (WPF)

Tags: wpf, vb.net, command

I am trying to write a command so that when a user clicks on a button, a different window opens.  So far I have this in my XAML:

```
<Window.CommandBindings>
    <CommandBinding
        Command="ApplicationCommands.Open"
        CanExecute="CanOpenWindow"
        Executed="OpenWindow">
    </CommandBinding>
</Window.CommandBindings
```

and

```
<Button
    Content="Open Another Window"
    Command="ApplicationCommands.Open"
    CommandParameter="????">
</Button>
```

In code I have:

```
Private Sub OpenWindow(sender As Object, e As ExecutedRoutedEventArgs)
   Dim win As New Window
   win = DirectCast(e.Parameter, Window)
   win.Show()
End Sub
```

I can't figure out what can replace the question marks to make this work.

PS: I think someone who has more reputation poi9nts than I should create a new tag called "Commanding".

Comment: `Commanding` is ***command***... Have you Googled your issue?

Comment: @Codexer  Yes, but "command" can also refer to the command window (which is the most common result when querying the web) while "commanding" is unique to the usage in Visual Studio.  Yes, I've consulted Prof. Google and, failing to get useful information, led to this post.

Comment: Ok then why cant you just wire up an event? Also there are a few ways to accomplish what you need, mediator, MVVM etc...

Comment: CommandParameters are used to define if a user can use the button or not based on some value. E.G If a user want to use a search function, I don't want the user to able to click on the search-button unless they have written something in a `TextBox`. The CommandParameters can help you check the value on the `TextBox` to see if it contains some text/value.

Comment: @Codexer  First, if I know how to "just wire up an event" I would not be posting my question.  Second, I already have the necessary event wired up, my problem is in evoking it.  Thus, your comment was unhelpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the `CommandParmeter` property to a window *type*:

```
<Button
    Content="Open Another Window"
    Command="ApplicationCommands.Open"
    CommandParameter="{x:Type local:Window1}">
</Button>
```

---

```
Private Sub OpenWindow(sender As Object, e As ExecutedRoutedEventArgs)
    Dim type = DirectCast(e.Parameter, Type)
    Dim win = DirectCast(Activator.CreateInstance(type), Window)
    win.Show()
End Sub
```

Comment: You (mm8) consistently know how to do what I need to do - thanks.